# How to regularly update a meteor collection from an external JSON feed?

Tags: meteor

I'm building an app that pulls its data in from a couple of external JSON feeds that I'm supplying from another domain.

I want to build collections on the server so that I can use $near location queries, but I'm going to need to check these JSON feeds regularly to see if they have updated, and if they have I'll need to update my collection accordingly.

Is there a 'standard' way of doing this? (checking what I have on the server is the latest version?)

## edit... more info!

My JSON feeds both have a unique identifier (called `url_title`, but definitely unique across all feeds) that I could use in an `upsert` if I could just figure out how to format the query. Would that work in combination with `setInterval`? One of my feeds looks like this:

```
[{"offer_title":"NEW TEST OFFER!!!",
   "url_title":"new-test-offer_144",
   "offer_desc":"description here",
   "offer_start":"2014-07-10",
   "offer_end":"2014-07-12",
   "offer_category":"food-drink",
   "offer_advertiser":"Testing Corp",
   "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-5.53596,50.12121]
    }
} ...
```

And I'm pulling in the data (currently client-side) like this:

```
Offers = new Meteor.Collection( null );

HTTP.get("http://myappurl.com/offers.json", function(err,result) {
    if (result.statusCode === 200) {
        respJson = JSON.parse(result.content);
        for (var i = 0; i < respJson.length; i++) {
          console.log('inserting '+respJson[i]['offer_advertiser']);
          Offers.insert(respJson[i]);
        }
        //Commented out because I need to move this server side
        //Offers._ensureIndex({location: "2dsphere"});
      }
      else {
        console.log(result.statusCode);
      }
});
```

If I wrap this in Meteor.setInterval and give it a relatively long interval time, would that work? What would the insert/upsert format look like?

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution:

Mirror your external feeds with a mongo collection. Just create a collection and periodically update it from the external feed. Write your queries and publications as normal.

Comment: That sounds good; how would I go about it though? With some kind of pseudo (node) cron? Or would I do it within the app itself?

Comment: You can create 'cron' jobs inside of meteor, just use Meteor.setInterval in your server side code, probably best to place it inside of Meteor.startup().